# Extracting part of a string using awk or gawk

Tags: awk

I have a file like this:

```
HMIC_insuff/out/expected_dcct_1kg_only10_1.res:---      rs4142674       4301956 T       C       0.950073        0.740579        0.895093        0.299186        0.628359        1.27505 1304    563     741     +       0.537017        0.553135        0

HMIC_insuff/out/expected_dcct_1kg_only11_16.res:rs10899221      rs10899221      76181631        A       G       0.0778374       0.414726        1.14734 0.189249        0.860697        1.52945 1304    563     741     +       1       0.848675        0

HMIC_insuff/out/expected_dcct_1kg_only11_17.res:---     rs61900305      82984402        A       C       0.125867        0.893738        1.06007 0.148316        0.839765        1.33818 1304    563     741     +       0.997527        0.705928        0
```

I was trying to get the number "11" or "10" in the first column from each of the string HMIC_insuff/out/expected_dcct_1kg_only11_17.res:---   (as you see the 11 is right after the string "only" or 10 is after the string "only") , I was trying multiple step of awk say defined the -F as _only and get the second field, and then repeatedly using different -F to isolate the number "11" or "10" from the first column. But somehow I am not able to do it even after couple of awk steps because I also need to get rid of the part attached to the "11" or "10" for example the part "_17.res---" or "_16.res:rs10899221".

I believe this can be solved probably using the expression in gawk, but I am very new to it, so I am not sure how to solve the problem.

Also I want my final table to look like this (so basically just the same table but having the first column containing the number after "_only" only):

```
11      rs10899221      76181631        A       G       0.0778374       0.414726        1.14734 0.189249        0.860697        1.52945 1304    563     741     +       1       0.848675        0

11   rs61900305      82984402        A       C       0.125867        0.893738        1.06007 0.148316        0.839765        1.33818 1304    563     741     +       0.997527        0.705928        0
```

thank you

Comment: What happened to the first line of data in the report? Did you mean it to go missing? Does it have to be `awk`?  I'd probably use `sed` for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` because it is quick and easy:

```
sed 's/^[^:]*only\(1[01]\)[^ ]*/\1/'
```

Note that this prints unmatched lines (those without 'only10' or 'only11').  If you want those omitted, then you use:

```
sed -n '/^[^:]*only\(1[01]\)[^ ]*/ s//\1/p'
```

I wouldn't use `awk` for this; if `sed` was not appropriate, I'd go for Perl.

---

If the number after 'only' can be one or two digits, then you need to use an appropriate regular expression instead of the one shown, which is carefully designed so that it only picks up 10 and 11 (possibly followed by other digits) as asked for in the question.  Please be careful when asking the question to distinguish between what applies to the specific sample data and what applies to the general case.  Ask about the general case, and then describe how it applies to the specific sample data.

Here's a variant that probably meets your clarified requirement.

```
sed -n '/^[^:]*only\([0-9]\{1,2\}\)_[^ ]*/ s//\1/p'
```

The regex looks for the start of line, a sequence of non-colons followed by 'only', then one or two digits (which are remembered), an underscore, and possibly some more non-blanks. For those lines that match, the whole of that pattern is replaced by the remembered one or two digits and then what's left of the line is printed.  If there was a three digit number, the line would not be printed.  If you don't care how many digits, you can use `\([0-9][0-9]*\)` instead. You could substitute `[^ ]` for `[^:]` without much likelihood of coming to any harm.

I write using the austere classic `sed` notations because it works everywhere.  Some versions of `sed` support more nearly [PCRE](http://pcre.org/)-like regular expressions.  I don't often use them precisely because they aren't portable and they aren't necessarily PCRE even though they use some of the notations also used by PCRE.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code. But the digit after "_only" can also be a single digit like 1, 2,3, 4, or two digis like 21, 22, 20.  Can you suggest a better solution?  thank you                  HMIC_insuff/out/expected_dcct_1kg_only8_3.res:--- rs17830872 12681367 C T 0.169253 0.313911 0.80268 0.131844 0.651009 0.989687 1304 563 741 + 0.997804 0.277798 0
HMIC_insuff/out/expected_dcct_1kg_only8_5.res:--- rs77837771 22984598 G C 0.0754496 0.263196 1.35721 0.200632 1.01466 1.81541 1304 563 741 + 0.950885 0.840956 0

Comment: I tried your code, and only able to extract 11, 10, 15 but not 1,5,9,21, 22, 17,18 if those numbers are after the substring "_only" in the first column. Also would you mind to explain little bit of your code, because I am very new to sed, thank you very much for your help.